# how to validate more than one field and display one error in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two field from and to.

```
   $this->form_validation->set_rules($time_am,'AM Time','required');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules($time_pm,'PM Time','required');
```

I dont want to validate separately. If any one or both are empty have to validate "The AM and PM Time field is required".

In DB i stored like this.

```
        $time_am    = $this->input->post('time_am');
        $time_pm    = $this->input->post('time_pm');
        if(empty($time_am) || empty($time_pm))
        {
            $time  = "NULL";    
        }
        else
        {
            $time   = $time_am." - ".$time_pm;
        }
```

Comment: use callback function fot it

Comment: i tried  something like this       function check_empty()
   {
    $time_am = $this->input->post('time_am');
      $time_pm = $this->input->post('time_pm');
     if (empty($time_am) || empty($time_pm)) {
   
      $this->form_validation->set_message('required field');
 }

Comment: Yes correct go ahead!!

Comment: @Saty how use this in set_rules. i have 2 diff field name

Answer (score 0):

You only need to do this

```
if( ! empty($time_am) ){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($time_am,'AM Time','trim|required|callback_valid_time');
}
else{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($time_pm,'PM Time','trim|required|callback_valid_time');
}

if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){
    ...
}
else{
    ...
}
```

Comment: how can i use in form_error('?').. normally we used field name but here how to echo from_error..

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found answer for my question.

```
function check_empty($key)
{
    if(!$key)
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_empty','both required field');
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;    
    }
 }


    $time_am    = $this->input->post('time_am');
    $time_pm    = $this->input->post('time_pm');
    if(empty($time_am) && empty($time_pm))
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('time_am','AM Time','trim|callback_check_empty');
    }
```